# FF Addon-sdk: easy way to avoid server scripts

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to, given a target website, avoid all the server-scripts. In order to  do that, I first downloaded the contents of that page and then created a pagemod that detects the URL. The problem is that, then, I want to load the stored contents but I don't know how to do it easily. For example, I've tried:

```
    new PageMod({
      include: /(http:\/\/)?(www.google)(.([a-z]){2,3}){1,2}(\/)?/,
      contentURL: data.url('google.html'),
      contentScriptWhen: 'end',
      contentScriptFile: [data.url('contentScripts/jquery.js'), 
                          data.url('contentScripts/handleQuery.js')],
      contentScript: 'alert("' + data.load('contentScripts/google.html') + '");',          
      onAttach: function getQuery(worker) { ... }
```

Where google.html is Google's main page. But it gives me a lot of errors...

Does someone know a better solution?

**EDIT**: The goal is to, somehow, avoid the scripts that a server can execute when you go to a website (PHP, C#, etc). I thought that if I download the page I only get the client-code (html, css, javascript, etc) so, if I load the page locally I can do that. The problem is that I don't know how, using the Firefox addon-sdk, to load a local page stored for example in the data folder. I hope this explanation clarifies a little bit.

Comment: what errors? I still don't really understand what you're trying to do here or why. Please add more explanation!

Comment: I added some explanaton. Tell me if it's still unclear.

Comment: well, I'm not surprised that you get a ton of errors on google's main page if you prevent AJAX from happening - all of google's web properties depend heavily on JS and service calls to function correctly. I don't think this is a problem the SDK can solve.